# Dynamic class for Html element breaking at space

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my ASP .Net project I have created the following function on a view (Razor):

```
@functions{

    public string GetClassFromLevel_Global(decimal level)
    {
        return level >= Model.global_limit ? "progress-bar progress-bar-success" : "";
    }
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
<div class=@GetClassFromLevel_Global(total.Value) ...></div>
```

What I get in return:

```
<div class="progress-bar" progress-bar-success="" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%"></div>
```

For some reason the returned string breaks at the space, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks shouldn't be an issue in a well formed HTML. However, your Razor syntax is problematic:

```
<div class=@GetClassFromLevel_Global(total.Value) ...></div>
```

Will generate this html:

```
<div class=progress-bar progress-bar-success ...></div>
```

The first element `progress-bar` will be parsed as the value of the `class` attribute where as `progress-bar-success` will be parsed as an attribute with no value. I suspect the output you are giving in your questions is copied from a browser developpers tool HTML inspection. If you quote the function call, you will get the expected result:

```
<div class="@GetClassFromLevel_Global(total.Value)" ...></div>
```

Will generate:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" ...></div>
```